# How to view HTTPWebRequest response?

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

```
Dim s As HttpWebRequest
Dim username= "username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("username")
Dim message = "message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("message")
Dim sep = "&"
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
sb.Append(username).Append(sep).Append(message)
s = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.website.com/?" + sb.ToString())
s.Method = "GET"
Dim result = s.GetResponse()
```

How do I reponse.write the result to the screen?
I get errors like..Value of type 'System.Net.WebResponse' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s.GetResponse() returns a [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx), which isn't something you can just print. The actual response data is in result.Headers and result.GetResponseStream(). You'll need to read the data from that (the way you'd read any Stream) into a String, and THAT you can output to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating a basic proxy.  What you need to do like Tridus said was get the response stream and then write the content from one to the other.  I have done this before in an open source project that may help you.

[Managed Fusion Rewriter Proxy Class](https://github.com/managedfusion/managedfusion-rewriter/blob/master/src/ProxyHandler.cs#L387)

I know this is C# but the process is still the same in VB.  And should look something like this:

```vb
Using responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Using bufferStream = New BufferedStream(responseStream, Manager.Configuration.Rewriter.Proxy.BufferSize)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}

        Try
            While True
                ' make sure that the stream can be read from
                If Not bufferStream.CanRead Then
                    Exit While
                End If

                Dim bytesReturned As Integer = bufferStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)

                ' if not bytes were returned the end of the stream has been reached
                ' and the loop should exit
                If bytesReturned = 0 Then
                    Exit While
                End If

                ' write bytes to the response
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReturned)
            End While
        Catch exc As Exception
            Manager.Log("Error on response: " + exc.Message, "Proxy")
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

*Please note this is a direct translation from my source, so you will have to make customizations for your own program.*